# Which library for a simple MPD client (text commands over tcp) in ocaml

Tags: ocaml

What library should I use in order to create a simple MPD client. The MPD (Musi Player Daemon) protocol is just based on text commands ended by '\n' over tcp.

Even if it exists a MPD lib, I really would like to try to create some tcp requests on my own, it is just to learn to use Ocaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Unix module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html) in the OCaml standard library should have everything you need for basic interactions.  The excellent [Unix system programming in OCaml](https://ocaml.github.io/ocamlunix/ocamlunix.html) book is freely available online and provides some examples which may be useful.  Chapter 6 covers sockets.

[Lwt](http://ocsigen.org/lwt/2.5.2/manual/) would be a good choice for a project like this if you want to support concurrency in your application.  It is probably simpler to start with the vanilla `Unix` module when learning the language though.

Have fun with the project!